# accessing IBOutlet properties from another class

Tags: ios, properties, connection, iboutlet

How do I access IBOutlets that have been created in another class?

here is my code...
 Class one

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (retain, readwrite)  IBOutlet UIView *myView;

@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController
@synthesize  myView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
@end
```

Class two

**.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
- (IBAction)accion:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnBack:(id)sender;
@end
```

**.m**

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ViewController2.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)accion:(id)sender {
    ViewController *a = [ViewController new];
    UIView *someView = [a myView];
    [someView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
- (IBAction)btnBack:(id)sender {
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

**why not works? no change the backgroundColor when return on my view**

Comment: in your `UIViewController2` class u create every time new object so every time your my change in memory. i alloc in `viewDidLoad` method like this.

Comment: The question is Do you open ViewController2 from ViewController and you want to change color of ViewController myView from ViewController?

Comment: I have a button use a segue modal in ViewController to change to ViewController2 then I try to access to myView and change backgroundColor but not works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you try to delegate pattern to set the values `Viewcontroller2.h` file
Add protocol like this...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@protocol tutorialDelegate <NSObject>   //set protocol
-(void)delegatesDescribedWithDescription;
@end
@interface ViewController2 : UIViewController
@property (weak, nonatomic) id<tutorialDelegate> tutorialDelegate1;
- (IBAction)accion:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)btnBack:(id)sender;
@end
```

after the declaring protocol in `viewcontroller2.m` file first synthesize and call method like this..

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController2 ()

@end

@implementation ViewController2
@synthesize tutorialDelegate1; // synthesize here
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)accion:(id)sender {
    ViewController *a = [ViewController new];
    UIView *someView = [a myView];
    [someView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
}
- (IBAction)btnBack:(id)sender {
    // Here we tell delegate to invoke method in parent view.
    [self.tutorialDelegate1 delegatesDescribedWithDescription
     ];
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}
@end
```

and finally  we implement this method in view `controller.m` file but first set delegate in `viewcotroller.h` file like this...

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "ViewController2.h" //import here
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <tutorialDelegate> //set delegate
@property (retain, readwrite)  IBOutlet UIView *myView;

@end
```

and `viewcontroller.m` file

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize  myView;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
    -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
   {
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"yourIdentifier"]) {
        ViewController2 *detailViewController =
            segue.destinationViewController;
         // here we set the ViewController to be delegate in
        // detailViewController
        detailViewController.tutorialDelegate1 = self; 
      }
    }
    // ViewController must implement tutorialDelegate's methods
// because we specified that ViewController will conform to 
// tutorialDelegate protocol
-(void)delegatesDescribedWithDescription
{   // here your code please
    viewTemp.backgroundColor =[UIColor redColor];
}
@end
```

Comment: @Fabio please try this may be it is helpful to you.

Comment: Woow this exactly what I'm looking for thanks. I tried several times and finally works. Thanks from Mexico =)

Comment: hi @ilesh i have a last question. in viewcontroller.m 

in detailViewController.tutorialDelegate1 = self;   

How do this in viewDidLoad? I try this but not works :(

    ViewController2 *detailViewController = [[ViewController2 alloc]init];
    detailViewController.tutorialDelegate1 = self;

Comment: i think in `ViewDidLoad` method the memory new memory allocation for viewcontroller2 but in segue method we get the already allocated viewcontroller2 that y it is not working in your case.

Comment: if you are using `xib` then after allocation in `viewDidLoad` method it is work. :)